# Bcp command into Microsoft Azure

Tags: python, pandas, azure, csv, bcp

I'm trying to use `bcp command` to append data into exist table in `azure` db.

When I'm exporting the csv\txt file directly from command line - it looks like a binary file, and then the import from this file pass fine.

But if I'm trying to take a `python pandas dataframe` which has the same data and save it as csv\txt, the content is different - there is no binary data - just the normal values.

But then, after the import from that file - there is no error but 0 rows imported...

How can I create csv from dataframe that will be the same as the bcp csv?

this is my working code (directly from command line):

```
--export
bcp "select * from tbl where val=1" queryout "Test\tbl1.csv" -S <server> -d <db> -U <user> -P <password> -q -n -t,

--import
bcp tbl2 in "Test\tbl1.csv" -S <server> -d <db> -U <user> -P <password> -q -n -t,
```

this is my python code:

```
import subprocess as sp
...
df0.to_csv('tm2.csv',encoding='utf8',index=None,sep=',',header=None)

cmd2='bcp tbl2 in "Test\tm2.csv" -S <server> -d <db> -U <user> -P <password> -q -t, -n'

sp.call(cmd2)
```

but the table tbl2 with no change.

Comment: Anybody? How can I generate the csv from pandas exatcly like it's generate from the bcp? what is the different?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your bcp command line. According to the offical document about [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017), the `-n` option means to use the native (database) data types of the data, which exports data as a binary format, please see below.

> -n Performs the bulk-copy operation using the native (database) data types of the data. This option does not prompt for each field; it uses
>   the native values.
>
> For more information, see [Use Native Format to Import or Export Data (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-native-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

However, in your scenario, to import/export csv format data file must to use `-c` option, see the explaination below.

> -c Performs the operation using a character data type. This option does not prompt for each field; it uses char as the storage type,
>   without prefixes and with \t (tab character) as the field separator
>   and \r\n (newline character) as the row terminator. -c is not
>   compatible with -w.
>
> For more information, see [Use Character Format to Import or Export Data (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-character-format-to-import-or-export-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

So if you want to import a csv data file exported from a pandas dataframe, the correct way is to use `-c` instead of `-n`, then it works for importing and exporting CSV format data file by bcp on SQL Database.